# Capture cell values of checked rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which has several columns holding text values and one column that’s a checkbox element. On a button click event, I’m trying to capture the text data for all elements across checked rows, but I’m having trouble accessing the text data of  elements of the checked rows.

I’m able to get the checked rows of the original table by doing the following:

```
var table =$(‘#TableID tr’).filter(‘:has(:checkbox:checked)’).find(‘td’);
```

This works, and, logging the resultant jquery object in the console, Im able to see the tds of interest.

However, I’ve not been able to retrieve and store the text values of each td of the “table” jquery object. Here’s what I have so far:

```
table.find(“tbody tr”).each(function() { var $tds=$(this).find(‘td’),comp_name=$tds.eq(0).text(),pos=$tds.eq(1).text(),address=$tds.eq(2).text();});
```

etc, basically storing explicitly all attributes of a row, and this is done on the checked rows. But this returns nothing. No error, no values. I’ve also tried other approaches but nothing seems to work.

How can I capture this text row data for checked rows?

Sample row:

Company | Position | Years | Applicable?
Google     | janitor    | 3        | (checked)
Nokia       | swe        | 1         | (unchecked)

In the above we’d want the text values for each of the attributes of just the first row

Comment: Can you include a sample row ?

Comment: Made an edit to show a sample row

Comment: @user6825056 sample in HTML please. It sounds doubtful whether your definition of attribute is the same as mine.

Comment: Slang is used for development, so tables aren’t written out in html. Instead gui elements, such as tables, are added in the slang environment, and html is generated from that code. Table data is given as a 2d array to a UI table element constructor and that returns the table. So for this case each row is defined as an array that includes strings and one checkbox element, and then those row arrays are pushed to a 2d table array that’s given to the dash_ui table slang function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is in the element to target and how to iterate them.
You were in fact quite close but your function wasn't returning anything.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var $trs = $('tr:has(:checkbox:checked)', 'table');
  var res = [];
  $trs.each(function() {
    $td = $(this).children('td');
    // This is the missing part
    res.push({
      comp: $td.eq(0).text(),
      pos: $td.eq(1).text(),
      add: $td.eq(2).text(),
    })
  })
  console.log(res);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="company">Company 1</td>
      <td class="position">Position 1</td>
      <td class="address">Address 1</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="company">Company 2</td>
      <td class="position">Position 2</td>
      <td class="address">Address 2</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="company">Company 3</td>
      <td class="position">Position 3</td>
      <td class="address">Address 3</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button>
Go to work
</button>
```